# iCloud Backing Up Multiple Files

Tags: icloud

I've got a problem with backing up multiple files to the cloud (HTML files).

Whenever I backup the files they are put in the cloud and removed from my device. ***But*** the structure in iCloud's Documents folder is strange:

NSLog output:

**Files in the cloud: file://localhost/private/.../Mobile%20Documents/...~com~nwt/Documents/File1_01-06-2013.html/
Files in the cloud: file://localhost/private/.../Mobile%20Documents/...~com~nwt/Documents/File1_01-06-2013.html/File1_01-06-2013.html
Files in the cloud: file://localhost/private/.../Mobile%20Documents/...~com~nwt/Documents/File1_01-06-2013.html/File2_01-06-2013.html
Files in the cloud: file://localhost/private/.../Mobile%20Documents/...~com~nwt/Documents/File1_01-06-2013.html/File3_01-06-2013.html
Files in the cloud: file://localhost/private/.../Mobile%20Documents/...~com~nwt/Documents/Rbi8Bookmarks.plist**

As you can see in the first instance, it makes a folder of the first html file, and then nests the complete array of html files in a folder by the name of the first file. But not so with a single file (the plist).

Any ideas? I've been looking at this problem all week and I'm getting nowhere.

Philip

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)backupToiCloud:(id)sender {

        NSString *directoryToCopyFrom = [[searchPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Notes"];
        NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumeratedDirectory = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:directoryToCopyFrom];
        NSString *filename;

        while ((filename = [enumeratedDirectory nextObject])) {
            if ([filename hasSuffix:@".html"]) {

                // First, copy the note files to the documents directory as a backup to be copied back after cloud backup is finished
                [fileManager copyItemAtPath:[directoryToCopyFrom stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]
                                     toPath:[documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:&error];
                NSLog(@"Files on my phone: %@", filename);

                [self performSelector:@selector(moveNotesToCloud) withObject:self afterDelay:3];

            }
        }
}

- (void)moveNotesToCloud {

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *directoryToCopyFrom = [[searchPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Notes"];

    NSString *filename;

    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumeratedDirectory = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:directoryToCopyFrom];
    NSURL *URLToBackup = [NSURL URLWithString:directoryToCopyFrom];

    while ((filename = [enumeratedDirectory nextObject])) {
        if ([filename hasSuffix:@".html"]) {

            NSURL *iCloudDocumentsURL = [[fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]; // Discovering iCloud URL
            NSURL *destURL = [iCloudDocumentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

            [fileManager setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:URLToBackup destinationURL:destURL error:&error];
            NSLog(@"Notes copied to the cloud: %@", error);

            NSString *path = [[searchPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Notes"]; // Does directory already exist?
            [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

        }
    } // end WHILE statement

    // Wait 5 seconds for the cloud to register the changes and then list them in the console
    [self performSelector:@selector(listNotesInThecloud) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0];


}

// THIS JUST LISTS THE FILES IN THE CLOUD
- (void)listNotesInThecloud {

    NSURL *iCloudDocumentsURL = [[fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]; // Discovering iCloud URL
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumeratedDirectory = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:iCloudDocumentsURL.path];
    NSString *filename;
    while ((filename = [enumeratedDirectory nextObject])) {
        if ([filename hasSuffix:@".html"] || [filename hasSuffix:@".plist"]) {

            NSURL *destURL = [iCloudDocumentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
            NSLog(@"Files in the cloud: %@", destURL);

        }

    } // end WHILE statement

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the help from a very kind developer. Please note the comments 'NEW'. Now the structure in the cloud Documents folder is as it should be, all the files in that very folder.

```
- (void)moveNotesToCloud {

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *directoryToCopyFrom = [[searchPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Notes"];
    NSLog(@"Move notes to iCloud, copy from: %@",directoryToCopyFrom);
    NSString *filename;

    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumeratedDirectory = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:directoryToCopyFrom];
    NSURL *URLToBackup = [NSURL URLWithString:directoryToCopyFrom];
    NSLog(@"Move notes to iCloud, backup url is: %@",URLToBackup);


    while ((filename = [enumeratedDirectory nextObject])) {
        if ([filename hasSuffix:@".html"]) {
            // NEW
            NSURL *srcURL = [URLToBackup URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename isDirectory:NO];

            NSURL *iCloudDocumentsURL = [[fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]; // Discovering iCloud URL
            NSLog(@"Move notes to iCloud, doc url is: %@",iCloudDocumentsURL);
            NSURL *destURL = [iCloudDocumentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename isDirectory:NO];
            NSLog(@"Move notes to iCloud, dest url: %@",destURL);

            // NEW
            if ([fileManager setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:srcURL destinationURL:destURL error:&error] == FALSE)
                NSLog(@"Notes copied to the cloud: %@", error);

            NSString *path = [[searchPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Notes"]; // Does directory already exist?
            [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

        }
    } // end WHILE statement

    [self performSelector:@selector(listNotesInThecloud) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0];


}
```